# How to set associations using namespaces and SQL tables with different names from those of Ruby on Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and a SQL database. I'm trying to rename database tables in order to reach "harmony of names" between RoR Models and SQL tables.

---

For example...

... in 'RAILS_ROOT/config/routes.rb' I have this:

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :accounts
end

namespace "second" do
  resources :profiles
end
```

... in 'RAILS_ROOT/models/account.rb' I have this:

```
has_one :profile,
  :class_name => "Second::Profile"
```

... in 'RAILS_ROOT/models/profile.rb' I have this:

```
belongs_to :account
```

.. in the SQL database I have tables named:

```
accounts
profiles
```

---

I would like to continue to use the syntax

```
Users::Account.find(1)
```

in my RoR application, but I would like to have my SQL tables name like so:

```
users_accounts
second_profiles
```

**How to do that?**

P.S.: I read [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) "table_name()" and "table_name_prefix" sections but I am not able to set those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code in your models:

```
class User
  set_table_name "users_accounts"
end

class Profile
  set_table_name "second_profiles"
end
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: In my case I have to set ' self.table_name_prefix = 'users_' ' from here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/table_name/class